# It is possible to have another WHERE in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to have history list that will only appear the date less than or equal today, and also time that is less than to this time.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    schedules
LEFT JOIN
    (special_details
    LEFT JOIN
        schedule_logs
    ON 
        special_details.id = special_details_id)
ON
    schedules.id = location_id
WHERE
    location_id = 146
AND date(dates) < ('2013-02-19')
  //this will check if schedule is lessthan the date and time for today.
  //and its not working...
    AND (WHERE
        date(dates) = ('2013-02-19')
        AND 
        date(end_time) < ('12:56:20'))
```

if the date and time is 2013-02-19 / 11:00:00 it should appear.
if 2013-02-19 / 1:00:00 should NOT appear.
BUT if 2013-02-18 / 1:00:00 it should appear as it is less than the date for today.

If you have better idea for HISTORY list please tell me. or add a link.

Comment: no, you can use case if

Comment: not sure, but shouldn't be `AND (WHERE` simply a `OR`?

Comment: dates == one date, right? And end_time == hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: why don't you try dates < NOW(), which will take care that the timestamp is less than current timstamp

Comment: @Minesh
I think that's not right.
if i will use less than(<) all date will be check including the date that is not equal for today.
so 2013-02-18 @ 1:00:00 will not appear.

Comment: I mean 2013-02-18 @ 11:00:00 will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    schedules
LEFT JOIN
    (special_details
    LEFT JOIN
        schedule_logs
    ON 
        special_details.id = special_details_id)
ON
    schedules.id = location_id
WHERE
    location_id = 146
    AND (
        date(dates) < ('2013-02-19')
        OR
        (date(dates) = ('2013-02-19') AND date(end_time) < ('12:56:20')
    )
```